# Why ExoPlayer in Android OS-10 shows black preview screen while preview

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am Recording the video in Landscape mode and showing the preview in portrait mode using Exoplayer while record the video continuously at the time change the orientation vice versa Once in while player preview showing a blank screen. 
 I am using Exoplayer 2.9.6  as a dependency on Gradle and using android OS version 10.

> E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22659-29]
>   setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: requested buffer count 2 is less than
>   minimum 3
>
> E/Surface: IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(2)
>   returned Invalid argument E/ACodec: native_window_set_buffer_count
>   failed: Invalid argument (22)
>
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal
>   runtime error.
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setSurface(Native Method)
>           at android.media.MediaCodec.setOutputSurface(MediaCodec.java:2042)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.setOutputSurfaceV23(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1014)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.setSurface(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:422)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.handleMessage(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:387)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.deliverMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:864)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.sendMessageToTarget(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:835)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.sendMessageInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:817)
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:330)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Comment: Did you play the file from local storage?

Comment: May I know which file format did u used for recording. and what is the encoding format used?

Comment: @MohanRajS I used .mp4 for recording. 
MediaEncoder
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 10 introduces new APIs to MediaCodecInfo for querying whether a codec is hardware accelerated, whether it’s software only, and whether it’s provided by the device manufacturer or the Android platform. ExoPlayer 2.11 surfaces this information in its own MediaCodecInfo class via new hardwareAccelerated, softwareOnly and vendor flags. These flags are accessible and (in most cases) set correctly even when running on older versions of Android.

Further reference:[ExoPlayer 2.11 -Resolve Media Codec Problems](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-11-whats-new-e0e0701e4b6c)

Comment: Did you tried this solution which proposed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361121/min-undequeued-buffer-count-exceeded