# Running CameraX in a service in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax

i want to create a class in Android Studio using Kotlin that runs Camera in background

```
class MyForegroundService : Service() {

 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
  val notification = createNotification()
  startForeground(1, notification)
  // **************** I want to add camerax here *****************************
  return START_STICKY
 }
}
```

to run the camera in background can you help me please

Comment: I dont think android allows using the camera in the background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: class MyForegroundService : Service() {

     override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
      val notification = createNotification()
      startForeground(1, notification)
      // **************** I want to add camerax here *****************************
      return START_STICKY
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to develop any ForegroundService for android?

Some answers already have been made on the Use of camera as ForegroundService. You can check the links below.

[Camera frames in a service / background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205661/camera-frames-in-a-service-background-process)

[Grafika, a dumping ground for Android graphics & media hacks.](https://github.com/google/grafika)

Comment: yes I just want to run the camera as ForegroundService